# footer not at the very bottom of page when you resize the height of browser window

Tags: html, css

When you resize the browser window height to the point where it enables scrolling, the footer moves from bottom of the page and creates a "gap"

I do not want to use POSITION: FIXED, as it does place the footer on the bottom of the screen, not the page, and later when I add more content it will cover the content below it.

The website uploaded: http://developerbay.000webhostapp.com/

footer css:

```
.footer {
    background-color: #940a0a;
    height: 55px;
    line-height: 55px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #e1dac5;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Footer HTML:

```
<div class="footer">
        <a>REGISTERED NAMES AND TRADEMARKS ARE THE PROPERTY OF THEIR RESPECTIVE OWNERS - Copyright © 2017 All rights reserved</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I understood you, this should fix it:

```
body{
    min-height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}
```